# NextJs TypeError: nextCallback is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

Its my first time use redux with next.js and I can't setup Redux with NextJs and I always get this error. I tried with another way but still I get more errors and i cant even config it.

and its full of error message.

```
TypeError: nextCallback is not a function
    at D:\Next Js\hotel\node_modules\next-redux-wrapper\lib\index.js:146:46
    at step (D:\Next Js\hotel\node_modules\next-redux-wrapper\lib\index.js:57:23)
    at Object.next (D:\Next Js\hotel\node_modules\next-redux-wrapper\lib\index.js:38:53)
    at D:\Next Js\hotel\node_modules\next-redux-wrapper\lib\index.js:32:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (D:\Next Js\hotel\node_modules\next-redux-wrapper\lib\index.js:28:12)
    at makeProps (D:\Next Js\hotel\node_modules\next-redux-wrapper\lib\index.js:135:16)
    at D:\Next Js\hotel\node_modules\next-redux-wrapper\lib\index.js:186:46
    at step (D:\Next Js\hotel\node_modules\next-redux-wrapper\lib\index.js:57:23)
    at Object.next (D:\Next Js\hotel\node_modules\next-redux-wrapper\lib\index.js:38:53)
```

This is Setup File

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { HYDRATE, createWrapper } from "next-redux-wrapper";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import roomsReducer from "./reducers/rooms";

const bindMiddleware = (middleware) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    const { composeWithDevTools } = require("redux-devtools-extension");
    return composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware));
  }
  return applyMiddleware(...middleware);
};

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  Room: roomsReducer,
});

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
    const nextState = {
      ...state, // use previous state
      ...action.payload, // apply delta from hydration
    };
    if (state.count.count) nextState.count.count = state.count.count; // preserve count value on client side navigation
    return nextState;
  } else {
    return combinedReducer(state, action);
  }
};

const initStore = () => {
  return createStore(reducer, bindMiddleware([thunkMiddleware]));
};

export const wrapper = createWrapper(initStore);
```

This is _app.js File

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import Layout from "./layout/layout";
import { wrapper } from "../Redux/store";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />;
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

And finaly its my page that I want to dispatch an action

```
import Home from "../components/Home/Home";
import { getAllRooms } from "../Redux/actions/index";
import { wrapper } from "../Redux/store";

export default function Index() {
  return <Home />;
}

export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  async ({ store }) => {
    await store.dispatch(getAllRooms());
  }
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [next-redux-wrapper TypeError: nextCallback is not a function error in wrapper.getServerSideProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68638862/next-redux-wrapper-typeerror-nextcallback-is-not-a-function-error-in-wrapper-ge)

Answer (score 7):

I found the following solution and followed the same tutorial.

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  (store) =>
    async ({ req, res }) => {
      await store.dispatch(getRooms(req));
    });
```

Reference: https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I have looked through the code several times and even though I am not a Next.js user I noticed that the app.js render code is not enclosed with a provider that wraps the store, I would expect to see something like this:

```
<Provider store={store}>
      <Layout>
           <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
</Provider>
```

Furthermore I would expect  .withRedux() to contain a createStore object(in your case the initStore). Like this:

```
export default withRedux(createStore)(
  withRouter(MyApp)
)
```

I hope this is of any help, if not let me know what issues you are facing.

Comment: I tried with a lot of ways, i use Provider in react but with next still not work and give me another error, so i did your changes but i face this error..


TypeError: (0 , next_redux_wrapper__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.withRedux) is not a function

Comment: I did some additional reading on the topic, Except for dispatching it works exactly the same as in React. I would suggest to create a PoC project with only Nextjs installed and follow this minimal setup tutorial: https://lukeliutingchun.medium.com/next-js-setting-up-a-redux-store-with-combinereducers-615b30e4432d

If that works include middleware like thunk and devtools, then integrate it into your current solution. That way you know for certain that the redux part is working.

Comment: i did it bro, i created new project and tried the way that you added on last comment copied all codes, but i get an error at preload the data from server side..
`//Preload from the server side
    ctx.store.dispatch({
      type: "reducerA/setCounter",
      payload: 10,
    });
`
and its the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined`

@RodneyWormsbecher

Comment: del package-lock.json and node modules and install
npm i --save --legacy-peer-deps

its works for me, no error anymore